# Java Regex Remove comma's between numbers from String

Tags: java

I am trying to parse a string, to remove commas between numbers. Request you to read the complete question and then please answer.

Let us consider the following string. AS IS :)

*John loves cakes and he always orders them by dialing "989,444 1234". Johns credentials are as follows" 
"Name":"John", "Jr", "Mobile":"945,234,1110"*

Assuming i have the above line of text in a java string, now, i would like to remove all comma's between numbers. I would like to replace the following in the same string: 
"945,234,1110" with "9452341110" 
"945,234,1110" with "9452341110"
without making any other changes to the string.

I could iterate through the loop, when ever a comma is found, i could check the previous index and next index for numbers and then could delete the required comma. But it looks ugly. Doesn't it?

If i use Regex "[0-9],[0-9]" then i would loose two char, before and after comma.

I am seeking for an efficient solution rather than doing a brute force "search and replace" over the complete string. The real time string length is ~80K char.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException

    {

        String regex = "(?<=[\\d])(,)(?=[\\d])";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
        String str = "John loves cakes and he always orders them by dialing \"989,444 1234\". Johns credentials are as follows\" \"Name\":\"John\", \"Jr\", \"Mobile\":\"945,234,1110\"";
        Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
        str = m.replaceAll("");
        System.out.println(str);
    }
```

**Output**

```
John loves cakes and he always orders them by dialing "989444 1234". Johns credentials are as follows" "Name":"John", "Jr", "Mobile":"9452341110"
```

Comment: +1. You don't need a character set (`[]`). (?<=\\d) would work just fine :)

Answer (score 3):

This regex uses a *positive lookbehind* and a *positive lookahead* to only match commas with a preceding digit and a following digit, without including those digits in the match itself:

```
(?<=\d),(?=\d)
```

Answer (score 0):

You couldtry regex like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "asd,asdafs,123,456,789,asda,dsfds";
        System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(?<=\\d),(?=\\d)", "")); //positive look-behind for a digit and positive look-ahead for a digit.
// i.e, only (select and) remove the comma preceeded by a digit and  followed by another digit.
    }
```

O/P :

```
asd,asdafs,123456789,asda,dsfds
```

Comment: This is the correct solution. Simple and elegant. Thank you.

Comment: Careful... a _negative lookahead for a letter_ is not the same as a _positive lookahead for a digit_. Depending on your input string, this solution may not work as expected...